# Polygonal modeling vs. digital sculpting

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Can anyone please explain the difference between polygonal modeling and digital sculpting?

Comment: The difference in what manners? The procedure of modeling, or the way the software processes the modeling?

Comment: I'd say, polygon modeling when you modify the geometry (extrude / fill faces etc) or edit it very much to *roughly* fit the sketch, while sculpting - you only slightly change vertices position to refine the shape and *exactly* fit the sketch.

Comment: The procedure of modeling. But I wouldn't mind If you could tell me also how the software processes the modeling.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98032/modeling-vs-sculpting-when-to-use and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93512/sculpting-vs-proportional-editing-differences

Answer (score -3):

In my personal opinion sculpting is better than polygon modeling - it's because in this world there is no perfection, so when you sculpt the model looks alive and like having a soul in it.

Comment: Welcome to bse. Philosophically one could choose to be of the opinion that _everything is perfect_.  Unfortunately on bse opinions don't make for good answers.