# Modeling vs Sculpting when to use?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

It's my first time to use blender. I've been looking for youtube tutorials and other use modeling, others are sculpting. I don't know what to use. Modeling seems more precise and more accurate but sculpting seems easier than modeling. I've been modeling an original anime style character for a while now but I'm sure if I'll continue that or switch to sculpting. What should I use and when to use these two? Also, is this that right place to ask these kind of questions?

Comment: It's not the best place to ask such broad and opinion based questions, although you can take this as an biased advice. Sculpt organic things and model hard surface ones. This is more or less general rule, but you can model an apple or sculpt robot, whatever is easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that modeling should be used to actually 'setup'  the model, while sculpting is for making the details in the model. This because, as you said, modeling is more precise, and you'd probably want precision in your models, (also you can use a mirror modifier if you want symmetry) and after that, say you're making a tree or something, you can sculpt it (unless you're making rocks or something). I saw a video where someone directly shows this. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB6NG-B-0kg&t=311s)

Answer (score 5):

While as Luke mentions this is mostly an opinion based question, subject to personal preference, and largely dependent on what you are trying to achieve, I'll only add that while I see as sculpting a good starting point for planning the base shape of a model or as a finalizing step to add fine details over it, I find that in most situations it is often not a good "final product" on its own.

Sculpting will frequently produce triangulated output and messy meshes especially if using *Dynamic Topology*-like features. This results in poor topology that is largely unsuitable for the most common tasks that follow to produce a proper final product, like UV Mapping, rigging, armatures, making it hard to animate, tweak or texture.

This will not yield a pleasant model to work with, easy to edit or alter, as such I see sculpting more as a starting point then a final result.

If you plan to unwrap or UV map your model, animate, use modifiers, optimize your mesh or do anything involving exporting elsewhere (like game engines) you will eventually need a good base model, hand modeled with intent and proper quad dominant [high quality topology](http://topologyguides.com).

Comment: I'm actually planning to use it in an indie game. What should I use then for a good final product?

Comment: A quad based topology model like the ones in the linked page