# Edit mode edges

Tags: sculpting

I'm quite new to sculpting in Blender and I have just finished making a human head.

I'm now trying to do skin texturing but every time I switch the edit mode I see a triangle edged wire which doesn't seem because it makes it hard to select edges smoothly and the edges are not straight.

Could anyone please tell me how I can fix this, I'm guessing its because I applied too much smoothing to the model but I've seen video tutorials on youtube and they used just as much smooth shading as i did.

Here is an image of the head in edit mode.

[image: preview]

Comment: doesn't seem right**

Comment: What do you mean by "skin texturing"? I'm assuming that you want to UV Unwrap your model, to do so you should first retoplogize it.

Comment: Sculpted meshes are rarely suitable as final product because of bad topology, one of the reasons is UV mapping the other is rigging and animation. as cgslav mentions you probably need to retopologize first. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98032/modeling-vs-sculpting-when-to-use

Comment: Yes, UV unwrapping is exactly what I wanted to do before adding textures to the model. I've never had to retopologise a mesh, could you please explain how i can do it or perhaps give me some links to websites or related articles that could be of any use.