# When should I retopologize?

Tags: retopology

So it's my first time modelling a character and I have a pretty dense mesh (suprised that my Laptop can still handle it). When should you retopologize a character? Before Hair and clothes so just the body or after?

Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98032 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with the face , add a plane rotated on you  left to right axis and then add a shrink-wrap modifier and also enable face snapping this will try their best in keeping your extrusions with the sculpted topology , keep the plane on the noseBridge and also add a mirror , then start extruding the side till the eyes and then take your extrusion around the eyes , like this you can cover the whole body properly , and try yr best keeping them quads.[image]
You can go around in this fasion